# MIMO multipath delay

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, multipath, mimo

How is multi-path delay dealt with in MIMO systems? Most of the theory I have read on MIMO doesn't address multipath delay and assumes the multipath interference is limited to secondary antenna transmitting or receiving(so the MIMO channel is a matrix).

Is multipath delay equalization addressed after the multipath matrix model has been inverted? How does it work?

Comment: In practical implementations, you first try your very best to convert your channel to be flat, so that you don't have to care about multipath, THEN apply MIMO processing. I.e., OFDM first to convert your wideband channel to many smaller channels that don't "see" the multiple paths, then OFDM. I tried to explain that in this answer:

Comment: (by the way, I'd *love* to see more mathematical foundation and applications for actual multipath MIMO for wireless comms, i.e. where you *don't* first divide the channel using CP-OFDM or filterbank multicarrier systems, but really, I'm not aware of a single MIMO system that doesn't assume single-path channels and goes through lengths to ensure them. The optimization problem of dividing a multipath-MIMO channel into orthogonal subchannels just seems to be too computationally complex for practical applications.)

Comment: (and to answer your last question: it simply *doesn't* work. You can't represent a multipath MIMO channel as $N_{TX}\times N_{RX}$ matrix; you'd need something higher-dimensional than a matrix. and then most of the decomposition math we use falls flat or becomes very hard.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So if you have a MIMO OFDM system how does it work? How does the process of estimating the channel matrix happen? I have seen deviation of ofdm synchronization but it always assumed SISO.

Comment: @MarcusMüller There are papers on frequency-selective MIMO detectors, but in practice if you have a wideband channel the best known option as far as I'm aware is to use frequency-domain equalization.

Comment: @FourierFlux There are entire books dedicated to MIMO OFDM...

Comment: @MBaz sure, but as said, if you model the MIMO channel to be a single matrix (with scalar entries), then every tx-rx subchannel needs to be representable by a single scalar, i.e. flat.

Comment: @FourierFlux exactly as I explained in the answer I linked to. You divide the wideband channel that is wide enough so that multipath is visible into many narrow channels that are flat. OFDM!

Comment: I'm a little confused, in SISO OFDM you partition the frequency domain as separate channels. It's not clear to me how this extends to OFDM. Are you saying you compute a separate Chanel matrix for every sub band?

Comment: yes, exactly that.

Comment: Ah thank you, I suppose the synchronization algorithm sends a training pulse for each frequency and then estimates the channel matrix? Or approximates it from a carefully selected subset of frequency bands?